# Amazon AWS and Beanstalkd queue Job not getting moved from current-jobs-delayed to current-jobs-ready

Tags: php, laravel, beanstalkd

I have installed beanstalkd in my amazon aws ec2 server. But when I queue the job it does move to current-jobs-delayed. But it does not move ahead towards current-jobs-ready even though timespan for delay is only 5s-10s.

Is there anything wrong in server setup or beanstalkd setup?

Help would be really appreciated.

Following is the code. I am using Laravel framework and other note my EC2 server has Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed.

```
class ShareOneCommentCommandHandler implements CommandHandler{

/**
 * Handle the command
 * @param $command
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($command)
{
    $date = Carbon::now()->addSeconds(5);
    Queue::later(
        $date,
        'Acme\Commands\Share\PublishPost',
        [  'uid'      => Auth::user()->id,
           'accounts' => $command->accounts,
           'message'  => $command->message,
           'link'     => $command->link,
           'title'    => $command->linktitle,
           'domain'   => $command->linkdomain,
           'image'    => $command->linkimage
        ]
    );
}

}
```

Comment: what command/function are you running to put a job into the queue?  Can you post the PHP code that does the insertion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Laravel myself, but I see that the `Queue::later()` can take either a `DateTime` (which `Carbon` extends), or a simple integer for 'number of seconds in the future'. The BeanstalkD protocol doesn't deal with dates itself, only the number of seconds.

If you can run jobs through Beanstalkd without the `later()` function (to confirm that the beanstalkd server and Laraval are generally working), then I would change the function to just use the number of seconds directly and see if that works.

```
Queue::later(5/*seconds*/, 'Command\Class', [...]);
```

Comment: I figure out the problem. It was issue with the Beanstalkd version. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installs old version of beanstalkd so I had to add PPA in order to install latest version. Thanks for the help.